# Count number of balls in each bin, given a two-element sequence of balls and bins

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, combinatorics

If I have a list:

```
{ball,ball,BINDIVIDER,ball,ball,ball,BINDIVIDER,BINDIVIDER,ball,BINDIVIDER,ball}
```

The balls and bins can be in any permutation.

Then, the following is clear: in bin one I have 2 balls, in bin two I have 3 balls, in bin three I have 0 balls, in bin four I have 1 ball, and in bin five I have 1 ball.

Can I put a list like this (above) into Mathematica, and get the counts of the balls in each bin? So, in this case I would put in `{1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1}`, and get out `{2,3,0,1,1}`.

Each output is a list with as many entries as bindividers, plus 1 (so just the number of bins).

I have tried using `SequenceSplit`, but this does not understand that empty gaps between two bins contain zero balls, instead splitting the list into concurrent sequences.

Comment: From some of the answers that differ when `BINDIVIDER` is found at the beginning and/or end of the list, you should state if you are assuming that there are always "invisible" `BINDIVIDER`'s at the beginning and end of the list.  Or, if true, (and I think equivalently) that $n$ `BINDIVIDER`'s means that there are $n+1$ bins.

Comment: There is no condition, so indeed the BINDIVIDER can be at any position.

Comment: Understood.  But does that mean that `{BINDIVIDER,ball,ball,BINDIVIDER}` should result in `{2}` or `{0,2,0}` ?

Comment: {0,2,0} is the correct output in this case

Comment: You might want to edit the question with that additional information.

Comment: Ok edited! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we were to use 0 instead of 2 as the bin divider...

```
list = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1} /. 2 -> 0

(* {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1} *)
```

... then we could write:

```
Total /@ Split[list, # != 0 &]

(* {2, 3, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

**Update**

Taking account of subsequent comments and the updated question...

```
count[list_] := Total /@ Split[Append[list, 0], # != 0 &]

count[{0, 1, 1, 0}]
(* {0, 2, 0} *)
```

and

```
# -> count[#] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 5] // Column
```

[image: combinations]

Answer (score 5):

It works if the data are given as a string instead of as a list:

```
StringLength /@ StringSplit["11211122121", "2"]
(*    {2, 3, 0, 1, 1}    *)
```

The conversion to string, if required, can be done with

```
StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}
(*    "11211122121"    *)
```

To address [@ciao's concern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244861/26598), add the [`All`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) option:

```
StringLength /@ StringSplit["11211122121", "2", All]
(*    {2, 3, 0, 1, 1}    *)

StringLength /@ StringSplit["11211122112", "2", All]
(*    {2, 3, 0, 2, 0}    *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe the current answers correctly produce the result you appear to be after (which seems to be a "stars and bars" representation).

This would be one way to do this:

```
bincnts = (Join[{0}, PositionIndex[#][0], {Length[#] + 1}] // 
     Rest[#] - 1 - Most[#] &) &;
```

To illustrate the difference, I'll use the currently most upvoted answer (though a spot check on another answer yields the same):

All possible configurations with two dividers (hence 3 bins) (*N.B.: I've used zero instead of 2 as the divider*):

```
test = Permutations[{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
```

> {{0,0,1,1,1,1,1},{0,1,0,1,1,1,1},{0,1,1,0,1,1,1},{0,1,1,1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1,1,0,1},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{1,0,1,1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1,1,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,0,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,0},{1,1,1,0,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,0,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,1,1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,1,0,0}}

Current answer results:

```
Table[StringLength /@ StringSplit[l, "0"], {l, 
  StringJoin @@@ (Map[ToString, test, {2}])}]
```

> {{5},{1,4},{2,3},{3,2},{4,1},{5},{1,0,4},{1,1,3},{1,2,2},{1,3,1},{1,4},{2,0,3},{2,1,2},{2,2,1},{2,3},{3,0,2},{3,1,1},{3,2},{4,0,1},{4,1},{5}}

bincnts results:

```
bincnts /@ test
```

> {{0,0,5},{0,1,4},{0,2,3},{0,3,2},{0,4,1},{0,5,0},{1,0,4},{1,1,3},{1,2,2},{1,3,1},{1,4,0},{2,0,3},{2,1,2},{2,2,1},{2,3,0},{3,0,2},{3,1,1},{3,2,0},{4,0,1},{4,1,0},{5,0,0}}

Note that the latter correctly accounts for the actual number of bins that must logically be present.

Compared to using stringsplit or total on list split, this is quite performant:

[image]

with considerable advantage on large cases:
[image]

Comment: +1 To resolve the differences in the answers, it seems the the OP needs to give more information about the structure of the lists.  Specifically, `bincnts` and the "Current answer" result in the same thing when `BINDIVIDER` is not the first or last element.  And given that the OP knows about combinatorics (from the profile), I'd say your approach and comment about stars and bars are right on the money.  One of the other answers matches yours except when `BINDIVIDER` is the last element.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly.

```
{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
     1} //. {x___, 2, 2, y___} :> {x, 2, 3, 2, y} // 
   SequenceSplit[#, {2}] & // # /. {3} :> 0 & // Map[Length]
```

Comment: Ok, so add 3's where there are no 1s, then replace them with the count 0 at the end. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice.  If you insert `/. {2, x___} :> {3, 2, x} /. {x___, 2} :> {x, 2, 3}` just before `SequenceSplit`, then I think you'll get the answer that matches that of @ciao.

Answer (score 4):

```
Split[{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}, SameQ] /.
  {x : {1 ..} :> Length[x]} /.
  {x : {2 ..} :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, Length[x] - 1]}
```

Note: your example has no divider as the first or last element. If an initial or final sequence of 1s can be empty -- that is, if the first or last element can be a bin divider -- the answer changes

Answer (score 2):

```
 list = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1} /. 2 -> 0;
```

A variation on ciao's approach for integer input with 0 as bin divider:

```
ClearAll[binCounts1]
binCounts1 = Differences @ Random`Private`PositionsOf[ArrayPad[#, {1, 1}], 0] - 1 &;

binCounts1[list]
```

> ```
>  {2, 3, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

A much slower alternative using [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
ClearAll[binCounts2]
binCounts2 = SequenceCases[ArrayPad[#, {1, 1}], 
  {0, a : Except[0] ..., 0} :> Length[{a}], Overlaps -> True] &;

binCounts2[list]
```

> ```
>  {2, 3, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

Using ciao's `test`:

```
binCounts1 /@ test == binCounts2 /@ test == bincnts /@ test
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {ball, ball, BINDIVIDER, ball, ball, ball, BINDIVIDER, 
  BINDIVIDER, ball, BINDIVIDER, ball};

f = ({0}~Join~(PositionIndex[#][BINDIVIDER] /. _Missing :> {})~
       Join~{Length@# + 1} // Differences) - 1 &;

f@list
```

> {2, 3, 0, 1, 1}

---

To test with an example similar to @WReach's:

```
t = Tuples[{BINDIVIDER, 1}, 5];
{#, f@#} & /@ t /. BINDIVIDER -> 0 // Grid
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};

Count[1] /@ SequenceCases[Append[2] @ list, {1...,2}]
```

{2, 3, 0, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
```

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[list /. 2 -> 0, s : {1 ..., 0} :> Count[s, 1]]

(*{2, 3, 0, 1, 1}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Position` then `Differences`

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {"ball", "ball", "BINDIVIDER", "ball", "ball", "ball", 
   "BINDIVIDER", "BINDIVIDER", "ball", "BINDIVIDER", "ball"};
On[Assert];
AllTrue[list, MemberQ[{"ball", "BINDIVIDER"}, #] &] // Assert
output = Differences[
   Flatten[{0, Position[list, "BINDIVIDER"], Length[list] + 1}]] - 1
```

```
{2, 3, 0, 1, 1}
```